# Can air conditioning units be rented in France?

Tags: france, camping, rental, caravans

We are going to spend a few weeks in a caravan in a French campsite over the summer, but our accommodation does not have air conditioning. Does anyone know if is it possible to rent an air conditioner in France and, if so, how to go about it?

Answer (score 3):

Yes it is possible to rent air conditioners, either from professional companies or from private individuals. I would recommend the latter as it will probably be cheaper.

If you use your favourite search engine to look for 'location climatiseur' or 'louer climatiseur', adding the name of the place you're going to visit, you will find several websites offering this service (most of them probably only in French though...).